# Length and midpoint of a line segment

Tags: linear-algebra

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMZ9o.jpg)

I just need some help going about this question. This question is confusing me and driving me insane. If anyone could work this out and show working out I would be really grateful.if someone could tell me how to work out a and b it would really help me out

Thanks

Comment: Explain what actually are your difficulties with the length and the midpoint of a segment

Comment: Il be honest. The whole time thing is confusing me

Answer (score 0):

a. You have to find the length of each of the three blue segments, then add them. The horizontal one can be read by the picture, for the other two, use the *Pythagorean theoem*. Don't be afraid of writing down $\sqrt{\ \ }$ symbol!

b. How much the sides of the small triangles relate to the sides of the whole triangle? 
So, the perimeter will be also the same ratio of the whole perimeter.

Comment: Sorry if this is too much to ask but can you solve it for me or go step by step. I'm confused